# C++ reference to volatile object - reasons and effects

Tags: c++, embedded, volatile

I'm working on existing C++ code that has `volatile` references to objects

`volatile vClass & vobj;`

I come from `C` so I'm familiar with `volatile` when used to access memory-mapped IO like this:

`*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x12345678) = 0x5`

**QUESTION**

What is the effect of applying `volatile` to (a reference to) an object?

I would guess that all of its data members inherit `volatile` but what about if a member function has non-volatile memory accesses like

`void vClass::AccessMem() {*((unsigned int *) 0x12345678) = 0x5;}`

Would that memory access too become volatile?

Comment: Are you sure you are programming in C, per your tags?  The C language does not have the scope resolution operator or references.

Comment: That's a reference to volatile object. References can't be volatile. Your member function doesn't access the object itself, so it's not clear what it has to do with anything.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i tagged `C` because it also uses `volatile`

Comment: @molbdnilo fixed. Why can't references be `volatile`?

Comment: @Adrian References refer to objects, but they are not objects. If you write `volatile vClass & vobj = obj;`, "vobj" and "obj" are synonymous. If you're familiar with "references" from Java or C# or Python or something, that's a different concept with (unfortunately) the same name.

Comment: @Adrian Don't tag a C++ question with C just because C has common features. So does Java and C# and Swift and Rust and many others. PHP uses curly braces, so it's also got things in common!

Comment: BTW, the C++ language has the `volatile` keyword, so you don't need the C language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function must be volatile qualified to be called from a volatile object:

```
int not_a_member;

struct vClass {
  int i;
  void set(int j) {
     i=j; //i is not accessed as a volatile
     static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),int&>);
     }
  void set_v(int j) volatile{
     i=j; //here i is accessed as a volatile 
     static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),volatile int&>);
     not_a_member=j;//here not a volatile access because "not_a_member" is
                    // not a member.
     //To understand what happen, since you are a C programmer it is going to be simple.
     //The volatile qualifier is actualy apply to the "this" pointer, 
     // which is a pointer to the object from which this member function is
     // called. So inside this function "this" as the type "volatile vClass"
     //Inside a member function, all access to member data, as "i" are
     //actualy short ends for "this->i". So in this access, "i" 
     //adopt the volatile qualifier of "this".
     //So the volatile qualifier just applies to the data member of the object.
     }
  }

void use_vClass(){
   volatile vClass x;
   x.set(10); //Do not compile: "Error:try to access volatile object as non volatile"
   x.set_v(10); //Compile
  }
```

So since from a volatile object or reference, you can just call volatile qualified member function, all data member access will be "volatile".

Comment: `is_same_v` doesn't exist

Comment: @Adrian It is `is_same<x,y>::value` in since C++14. It is declared in `<type_traits>` header.

Comment: Can you provide a doc link? `C++14 is_same_v` doesn't return an authoritative source.

Comment: nvm I found it on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same): `inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;`

Comment: @Adrian My mistake, it was introduced in C++17

Comment: So if a function is given the `volatile` qualifier, ALL memory accesses inside it become volatile?

Comment: @Adrian, if a member function is given the volatile qualifier, memory acces to the data member of the object argument become volatile. The object argument is the one at the left of the dot in the expression `obj.member_function()` OK I had something in the code of my answer to make it clear.

Comment: In your `static_assert`, why is the second argument `int &` instead of `int` since `i` is just `int i`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163509/discussion-between-oliv-and-adrian).

Comment: @Adrian If I had written `decltype(i)` this is what I would have got: just `int`, because decltype will give me the declaration type of `i`. But I used `decltype((i))` notice the extra parenthesys, in this situation decltype give me the type of the evaluation of the expression `i` or equivalently `this->i`.

Comment: why isn't the type of `this->i` also just `int`?

Comment: @Adrian Look [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4) decltype(this->i) would also give `int` the important is the parenthesys, decltype((this->i)) would give `volatile int&`

Comment: in that case, what do you gain from adding `()` to elicit `int&` instead of just `int`?

Comment: @Adrian, inside set_v, decltype(i) is int. It is not interesting. But decltype((i)) is *volatile* int i. It was to show you that the `i` expression inside `i=j` has type `volatile int &`. Actualy what is ininteresting is `decltype(i)` since it says you what you can directly read inside the class. I did not want to trick but help you. You would learn a lot reading a book about c++.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference to a volatile, rather than volatile reference (the latter makes no sense anyway).

It is akin to:

```
volatile char * ptr = ...;
```

The memory at ptr can change without notice but ptr itself is stable (unlike if it were

```
char * volatile ptr = ...;
```